# Match multiple keys into pattern

Tags: java

I have this text from file which I would like to get values using pattern match:

```
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 100000
-->
```

I tried this:

```
     out.println("<tr>");
     out.println("<td>" + fullPackagePath + "</td>");
     out.println("<td> .sql </td>");

     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(?<key>([\\w]+)?): (?<value>(.+)?)");
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
     boolean found = false;

     while (matcher.find())
     {
       if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
         out.println("<td>" + matcher.group("value") + "</td>");
       }

       if (matcher.group("key").equals("description")) {
         out.println("<td>" + matcher.group("value") + "</td>");
       }

       found = true;
     }

     if(!found){
       out.println("<td> N/A </td>");
     }
     out.println("<tr>");
```

If the Spring pattern is not found I get for the first cell only `<td> N/A </td>`. I can use for every cell value Pattern matcher but the code will be huge. Is there nay way to print `<td> N/A </td>` if value into if check is not found?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more on what is the current output and what you want it to be? Currently it is unclear to me what the question is.

Comment: A you can see the table has 4 cells - fullPackagePath, .sql, author, description. If the match pattern don't find for  `author` and `description` text I want to print into those cells `N/A`

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend separating the data reading and writing - that will simplify the code.
So that you can firstly read all required data, and then write the values which were read or default values.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(?<key>([\\w]+)?): (?<value>(.+)?)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    String author = "N/A";
    String description = "N/A";
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
            author = matcher.group("value");
        }

        if (matcher.group("key").equals("description")) {
            description = matcher.group("value");
        }
    }
    out.println("<tr>");
    out.println("<td>" + fullPackagePath + "</td>");
    out.println("<td> .sql </td>");
    out.println("<td>" + author + "</td>");
    out.println("<td>" + description + "</td>");
    out.println("<tr>");
```